# Find the argument of this complex number

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose I have two complex numbers $z$ and $a$, such that $$z=(-1)a^{3\pi i}$$

Moreover, I know that the argument of $a$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$.

My reasoning was that argument of a complex number, seems to behave like the natural log. For example, arg(ab)=arg(a)+arg(b).

Hence,
$$arg(z)=arg(-1)+arg(a^{3\pi i})$$
$$arg(z)=arg(e^{\pi i})+3\pi i\space arg(a)$$

Hence,

$$arg(z)=\pi+\pi^2 i$$

However, there seems to be something wrong with my reasoning, since I don't expect the argument to be complex. Can someone point out where exactly I went wrong, and how to solve this kind of problem ?

Comment: I don't think the arg behaves like a log.

Comment: $\arg(a^{3\pi i}) = 3 \pi i \arg(z)$ *cannot* be correct, as you already observed. Note also that complex exponentiation is a multi-valued function in general, and the value of $a^{3\pi i}$ depends on which branch of the logarithm you choose.

Comment: $\arg a$ is of no use and $\arg z=\operatorname{Im} (\operatorname{Log}(z))\equiv\pi+3\pi\ln|a|\bmod{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 1):

We will calculate the principal argument of your complex number, that is $Argz$.

Consider $a=re^{i\theta}$. Then $Argz=\theta=\pi/3$. So $z=-1a^{3\pi i}=-1re^{i\frac{\pi}{3}\cdot3i\pi}=-re^{\pi^2}$ which is a negative real number, hence the principal argument is equal to $\pi$